# "product.tags" in shopify cart

Tags: shopify

I'm looking to display a specific image (with outbound link) in the HTML of the "Thank You" page of my Shopify Store.  I want it to display if there are any products with a specific Tag (`stb`) in the cart

```
{% for product in cart.items.products %}
{% assign product_tags_string = product.tags | join ' ' %}
{% if product_tags_string contains 'stb' %}
<p><a href="http://www.sharethebus.com" target="_blank" title="Book your bus ticket here"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0256/7469/files/FB_Meals_Token_large.png?11171876204102072109" /></a>
</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `item in cart.items` then item has product has tags... `{% if item.product.tags contains 'stb' %}... do that thing`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
{% assign product_tags_string = item.product.tags | join ' ' %}
...
{% endfor %}
```